# Is it possible to create a cookie from a Native Android App?

Tags: android, cookies

I've seen several questions on so regarding creating a cookie from Android using WebViews or in relation to HTTP post and get calls, however what I would like to do is set a cookie on the device that basically says "this app is installed" so that when users navigate to the mobile website later on (via chrome browser), it will detect the cookie so they do not get the nag screen asking them to download the app.

I'm guessing there is a security issue related to writing an HTTP cookie directly from a native app?  But perhaps using a webview and making a request to my mobile website and storing the cookie that way is possible?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

> I'm guessing there is a security issue related to writing an HTTP cookie directly from a native app?

Not only that, but there are many browsers available for Android. So you have many security issues, one per browser. It is theoretically possible that one or more browser makers have an API that allow third-party apps to set cookies. I am not aware of any that do.

> But perhaps using a webview and making a request to my mobile website and storing the cookie that way is possible?

At best, that will store a cookie for use by `WebView` widgets within your app. The operation of a `WebView` in your app has no impact on the operation of any of the many Web browsers that are available for Android.